# Cannot access Mamp Start Page / Localhost on firefox but can on chrome

Tags: firefox, mamp

As the question states I cannot access the Mamp start page/localhost on firefox anymore, this seems to have come out of the blue as I could a few weeks ago.

The url is: 'http://localhost:8888/MAMP/?language=English'

This works fine in chrome but not in firefox.

The message I get is:

'We can’t connect to the server at localhost.'

How can I diagnose this or does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Can you try incognito mode in Firefox?

Comment: It seems this is something to do with firefox forcing https on localhost I am just using chrome for now.